# SPARQL fill empty value with closest value match in time

Tags: sparql

I have data that looks something like this:
[image]
simplest case example data:

```
@prefix sphn: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:patient1 a sphn:Patient ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission1 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission2 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission3 .

ex:patient2 a sphn:Patient ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission4 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission5 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission6 .

ex:patient3 a sphn:Patient ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission7 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission8 ;
    sphn:hasAdmission ex:admission9 .

ex:admission1 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "70"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:bodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "180"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "male"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission2 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2005-02-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "80"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:BodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "185"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission3 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2020-03-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "female"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission4 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-04-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "80"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:bodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "175"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "male"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission5 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-05-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "68"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:bodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "165"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "unknown"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission6 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "72"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "female"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission7 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "75"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:BodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "170"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "Male"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission8 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-08-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "70"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:BodyHeight [a sphn:BodyHeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "170"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "cm"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "unknown"^^xsd:string] .

ex:admission9 a sphn:AdministrativeCase ;
    sphn:admissionDate "2019-09-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sphn:bodyWeight [a sphn:BodyWeight ;
                    sphn:hasQuantity "78"^^xsd:float ;
                    sphn:hasUnit "kg"^^xsd:string] ;
    sphn:gender [a sphn:AdministrativeGender ;
                sphn:hasGender "female"^^xsd:string] .
```

and would like to deal with missing values. See below my data fetched with query:
[image]

query:

```
select ?patient ?s ?admissionDate ?bodyWeight ?bodyHeight ?gender where {
    ?patient ?something ?s .
    ?s a sphn:AdministrativeCase.
    ?s sphn:admissionDate ?admissionDate .
    OPTIONAL {?s  sphn:bodyWeight/sphn:hasQuantity ?bodyWeight}
    OPTIONAL {?s    sphn:BodyHeight/sphn:hasQuantity bodyHeight.    }
    OPTIONAL {?s    sphn:gender/sphn:hasGender ?gender }               
} ORDER BY ?admissionDate
```

I would like to find a way to deal with the missing values. In the simplest case as displayed above, only 1 field is missing for each patient, for a single admission. However, generically, I would like to fill the empty value for property X, with the value of Property X from a different admission, which is closest in time (in the past) to the admission that has the empty value.

Something along the lines of
`BIND ( IF (BOUND (?bodyHeight), ?bodyHeight , ?closestBodyHeight)  as ?FinalBodyHeight  ) .`

The problem becomes: How do I calculate the closest body height (temporally speaking), to the one in EACH unbound triple?

With subquery I'm running into the problem that I cannot access the variables of my outer join from within my inner join to do the comparison with, and if I work with a simple coalesce, or bind(if(bound, I can't compute the closest on the spot.

what am I missing? Is this possible?
Thanks in advance for any tips & tricks, I can't imagine this is a new problem, but I have not found any quite like it on Stackoverflow or BDC's Learning SPARQL...

Update:
I think I'm closer:
I now have the closest date for each value, but still need to figure a way to replace the empty value with the value on the closest date.

```
 PREFIX sphn: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT ?patient ?admissionDate ?BodyWeight ?BodyHeight ?Gender (MAX(?otherDate) AS ?closestDate)

WHERE {{
    ?patient ?hasAdmission ?otherS .
    ?otherS a sphn:AdministrativeCase .
    ?otherS sphn:admissionDate ?admissionDate .
        
    OPTIONAL {?otherS sphn:bodyWeight/sphn:hasQuantity ?BodyWeight.}
    OPTIONAL {?otherS sphn:BodyHeight/sphn:hasQuantity ?BodyHeight.}
    OPTIONAL {?otherS sphn:gender/sphn:hasGender ?Gender.}
    }
      OPTIONAL{?patient ?hasAdmission ?s .
      ?s a sphn:AdministrativeCase .
      ?s sphn:admissionDate ?otherDate .
      FILTER (?otherDate < ?admissionDate)
    }
    } GROUP BY ?patient ?admissionDate ?property ?value ?BodyWeight ?BodyHeight ?Gender
```

[image]